# ASP.NET Core alternative to ServerInfo.GetHtml()?

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a page which shows my server information in ASP.NET through `Html.Raw(ServerInfo.GetHtml());`. I want to display the same information with ASP.NET core, but there's no ServerInfo and I can't find any way to get similar information.

Is there a way to get the same info?